# How to achieve jQuery slide (slideDown, slideUp) methods in D3.js

Tags: d3.js

How can I apply [`slide`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp) methods of jQuery to a non-SVG DOM element in d3.js?

Is there something I can use out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's nothing out of the box, but you can do this by simply animating the relevant dimensional attributes, e.g. slide down would be something like

```
d3.select("#element").attr("height", 0)
  .transition().duration(500).attr("height", realheight);
```

Depending on what you want to animate, you might have to work with clip paths to hide part of the element as it is being slid in.

You can of course simply use the JQuery methods. There should be no problem with that unless you want to run D3 transitions on the same object at the same time.